# How to turn users relationships to something new? for example relationships with ads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I tried to make relationships between user and ads according to a tutorial.
For that I divided the code into two controllers: users, ads also ads_subscriber and equivalent models. The problem thats i receive empty arrays.

let’s assume a logic:

```
user -have - list of ads. 
ad - have - list of users.
```

model/ad

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :reverse_ads_subscribers, foreign_key: "subscriber_id",
                               class_name:  "AdsSubscriber",
                               dependent:   :destroy
has_many :liked_ads, through: :reverse_ads_subscribers
```

model/user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :ads_subscribers, foreign_key: "liked_ad_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :subscribers, through: :ads_subscribers
```

model/ad_subscriber

```
class AdsSubscriber < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :liked_ad, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :subscriber,  class_name: "Ad"
```

controller/ads

```
def subscribers
@ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
@ads = @ad.liked_ads.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

controller/users

```
def liked_ads
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@users = @user.subscribers.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

database/ads_subscribers

```
id | liked_ad_id | subscriber_id | created_at|
----------------------------------------------
1  | 29          | 3             | date      |
```

I receive empty @users and @ads despite the fact, that the database filled

Comment: It is still a bit fuzzy. As it is, it shows that `subscriber` is an  Ad and `liked_ad` is a User?

Comment: `subscriber` is a User and `liked_ad` is an Ad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `subscriber` is a User and `liked_ad` is an ad:

```
class AdsSubscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :liked_ad,    class_name: "Ad"
    belongs_to :subscriber,  class_name: "User"
```

And the object classes:

```
Class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many     :adssubscribers, 
                 foreign_key: "liked_ad_id",
                 dependent: :destroy
    has_many     :subscribers,    through: :adssubscribers
```

and

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many     :adssubscribers,
                 foreign_key: "subscriber_id",
                 dependent: :destroy
    has_many     :liked_ads,      through: :adssubscribers
```

Then, you keep your controller methods almost as they are:

```
def subscribers
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    @ads = @ad.subscribers.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

and

```
def liked_ads
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.liked_ads.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks a lot. I will go to think why this happened.

Comment: You will have to look at associations as spoken expressions. ActiveRecord has worked a lot on that. So, `a user has many ads he likes` will translate into `(User.rb) has_many :liked_ads`, which are a subset of all ads (`Ad.all`), thus ads...